# Is a .htaccess rewrite rule a potential performance issue?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, performance

I use a .htaccess rewrite to redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/redirect-to-this-subfolder/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain-to-redirect-to-subfolder-of-ditto\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /redirect-to-this-subfolder/$1 [L]
```

**Could that become a performance issue for a heavy trafficed site?**

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer. No. Absolutely not.

There was a period where people on the net claimed that is was, however, at the time this was going on, Apache had already made changes quite a long time before that make the whole argument moot. It was major-league silliness then, and yet, it still echoes today.

The .htaccess file is cached within the Apache process and a trigger set so that if the file is modified, it gets loaded. There is no re-reading of the file over and over as many claim. If this were true, then the Apache programmers would have to climb a high ladder into the clouds and look up to see poor.

You can load the booger-snots (official technical term) out of your .htaccess file and there will be very little cost in doing so. The caveat is that processing any .htaccess file is recursive. This means that as a rule is applied, the whole set of rules are reapplied. In this, any sets of rules not written properly can cause more than the single recursion. Still, this is so tiny in the world of 2.4Ghz 16 core CPUs that any complaints in any regard is beyond laughable.

In short, get a beer and do not worry about it.

Comment: I agree, the above rewrite in .htaccess is not going to cause a performance issue. However, do you have a reference regarding the "cached within the Apache process" claim? .htaccess files might well be cached by the underlying OS in the (disk) _page cache_ and I would think that Apache will cache .htaccess files _per request_, but I have seen nothing to suggest that Apache caches them for any longer?

Comment: In fact, I have read that [Apache does not cache .htaccess files _between requests_](http://www.jefftk.com/p/apache-doesnt-cache-htaccess-configs). And, importantly, the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) state that there is an "additional file-system access" for every directory along the requested filesystem path, "every time a document is requested". (?)

Comment: @w3dk We are both right. Not all OSs are created equal. Not all file system triggers exist for all OSs. I got this about a decade ago from Apache as a performance change when Apache would not update an .htaccess file before 5 minutes. Then, all of a sudden, it would with a newer version of 1.??. At that point Apache did appear to cache the .htaccess from the web root as they claimed using the system I ran at the time. Even if file system triggers are not available, the file system will return a modified date with a simple file request without reading the file. That would be a smaller hit.

Comment: I merely note that @closetnoc’s answer contradicts httpd’s documentation on this subject: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when